# Calculating for each row in a dataframe

Tags: r, data.table

Given a dataframe

```
  ID days dose1 dose2 dose3 dose4  pattern
1 TM    2  11.0    45   0.2   0.1    spots
2 ZZ   18   2.0     6   8.0   0.0 no spots
3 YY    5   0.4     8  10.0  20.0 no spots
4 GG    5   0.4     8  10.0  20.0    spots


df <- structure(list(ID = c("TM", "ZZ", "YY", "GG"), days = c(2L, 18L, 
5L, 5L), dose1 = c(11, 2, 0.4, 0.4), dose2 = c(45L, 6L, 8L, 8L
), dose3 = c(0.2, 8, 10, 10), dose4 = c(0.1, 0, 20, 20), pattern = c("spots", 
"no spots", "no spots", "spots")), .Names = c("ID", "days", "dose1", 
"dose2", "dose3", "dose4", "pattern"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

I would like to calculate for each row as given below and summarize it to pattern "spots" and "no spots" -

```
dfx <- df[, list(
  Cal1 = sum(dose1>0)/days, 
  Cal2 = sum(dose2>0)/days, 
  Cal3 = sum(dose3>0)/days, 
  Cal4 = sum(dose4>0)/days
), by=pattern]
```

Is there anyway I can calculate as above for each row and add it to the data frame dfx?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want to calculate: an indication of the expected output would help.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to save the calculations to a separate data.frame

```
df[, paste0("Cal", 1:4) := .(sum(dose1>0)/days, 
                             sum(dose2>0)/days, 
                             sum(dose3>0)/days, 
                             sum(dose4>0)/days), by = pattern]
df
#   ID days dose1 dose2 dose3 dose4  pattern      Cal1      Cal2      Cal3       Cal4
#1: TM    2  11.0    45   0.2   0.1    spots 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
#2: ZZ   18   2.0     6   8.0   0.0 no spots 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.05555556
#3: YY    5   0.4     8  10.0  20.0 no spots 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.20000000
#4: GG    5   0.4     8  10.0  20.0    spots 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.40000000
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have many of those `dose1`, `dose2`, etc. columns it becomes cumbersome to write a separate expression for each output column `Cal1`, `Cal2`, etc. Instead, `data.table` syntax allows to write concisely

```
df[, paste0("Cal", 1:4) := lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x > 0) / days), 
   by = pattern, .SDcols = paste0("dose", 1:4)]
df
#   ID days dose1 dose2 dose3 dose4  pattern      Cal1      Cal2      Cal3       Cal4
#1: TM    2  11.0    45   0.2   0.1    spots 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.00000000
#2: ZZ   18   2.0     6   8.0   0.0 no spots 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.1111111 0.05555556
#3: YY    5   0.4     8  10.0  20.0 no spots 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.20000000
#4: GG    5   0.4     8  10.0  20.0    spots 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.4000000 0.40000000
```

Comment: Nice, `dplyr` has comparable shorthand syntactic sugar, although that make the expression even simpler imo.